# Online GIS Masters / MBA / MS / MA with a focus on business

Tags: education

Does anyone know of any GIS graduate programs that focus on the business elements of GIS? I am thinking of something like an MBA but with a GIS focus or a MA / MS with a business focus. Online only. Something like but GIS and Business Management. A web search is coming up with little.

Comment: welcome to GIS@SE. Your link did not format correctly. The markdown should be like this: [foo](http://foo.com)

Comment: http://gis.usc.edu/ has an online masters in GIS & Business

Answer (score 1):

Try [**unigis.org**](http://www.unigis.org/), a provider of online distance learning education in GIS.
It has three MSc programs:

- **GIS**: a broadly based postgraduate qualification in the field of GIS
- **Applied GIS**:  GIS-based methods for monitoring the social/human and natural environments.
- **GIS Technology**: software engineering that underpins database and web applications in a GIS context

I imagine you may be able to focus the second one (Applied GIS) on business aspects of social/human environments.

Comment: Nice link. Very competitive costs.

Answer (score 0):

Salisbury University in Maryland has one as well. [MS in GIS and Business Management](http://www.salisbury.edu/geography/msgism/). It has been in operation since 2007 and is fully online.

I did find this [ranking](http://www.justinholman.com/2014/05/16/top-10-on-line-gis-masters-degree-programs/) that places USC and Salisbury in the top 10. The USC one is more GIS for business (business uses of GIS) whereas the Salisbury one is GIS Management. It targets GIS professionals in managements positions.